# Find each row that has matching values in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that we use to manage our upcoming policy renewals. Some clients have multiple policies that are due at the same time, which are each shown on a separate row, but we treat them as a single transaction.

I have a userform to submit tasks to our administration team, which is called by a command button visible from a specific cell in each row. I then use `ActiveCell.Row` to pre-fill some of the form details.
It has a checkbox to indicate when a task is for all policies and a msgbox that tells the user how many policies there are. 
I've used this code to do that

```
Dim strCount As String
strCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), TxtClient.Value)
```

This works fine and returns the right value however I need to search column D:D for matching renewal dates as well and only count the rows that match both columns.

Later in my code, I also need to loop through all of these rows that match both client name & renewal date and add a Request ID in Column A.

I’ve been searching for a solution to this all day and come up empty handed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't you use AutoFilter?

Comment: Why do you need counting "the rows that match both columns"? In order to write something in A:A column if both C:C and D:D match your criteria, you do not need a preliminary count. Do you make this record in A:A only if there are more such policies occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the preliminary counting would be not necessary, please test the next (simple) code:

```
Sub testFindMatching()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
   Dim strCriteria As String

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   strCriteria = TxtClient.Value & CStr(DateValue(txtSomethingElse.Value)) 'use here your appropriate source for 'SomethingElse'
   For i = 2 To lastRow
      If sh.Range("C" & i).Value & sh.Range("D" & i).Value = _
                   strCriteria Then sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "RqID" 'Your "request ID" to be filled in A:A
   Next i
End Sub
```

If the range to be processed is very big, I can also post a faster version using arrays.

In fact, the faster variant will work well in any situation. I will also let the first version, which is easy to be understood by somebody not so familiar with arrays:

```
Sub testFindMatching_Arrays()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
   Dim arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, strCriteria As String

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("C2:D" & lastRow).Value
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 1)
   strCriteria = TxtClient.Value & CStr(DateValue(txtSomethingElse.Value)) 'use here your appropriate source for 'SomethingElse'
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
      If arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) = strCriteria Then
          arrFin(i, 1) = "RqID" 'Your "request ID" to be filled in A:A
      Else
          arrFin(i, 1) = sh.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
      End If
   Next i
   sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Edited: Adapted the code to also work with second parameter (`As Date`).

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, Thank you for this. I have tried your first sub here. It works perfectly when I did it without the second criteria (RenDate) but it won't work with the RenDate included. Is this because it's a date? The worksheet is formatted as a date in this column and i have used ```strRnl = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, CDate(TxtRenDate)), "[$-en-UK}]dd-mm-yyyy;@")``` to convert my userform textbox value back into a date, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing it in the search for a match?

Comment: @NicKitty: Is the date format in both cases (on the sheet and on the text box)? If yes, it should work without any change. If not, we must make some adaptations. But, before that, can you state that **all the time the second parameter will be a date**? Or only sometimes...? Now I cannot open my laptop. In about two hours I will be able to do that, but I need your statement on the  above issue...

Comment: The sheet is definately formatted as a date and I've presumed that adding the ```Format(DateAdd)``` into my sub has converted my text box into a date format also. But maybe that isn't the case? The renewal date will always be the second parameter.

Comment: @NicKitty: How the date is formatted in the sheet is not so important. VBA convert it in Date when place it in the array element. But in the default format, according to localization... You can see how the default format looks in your case using Debug.print Date. If it looks exactly like in your sheet and text box, the code should work like it is. The code works with strings. Only strings can be concatenated. But I adapted the code to be working even if the format (in the text box) is not the default one. Please refresh the page (this one) and use the last adapted code. Some feedback = good...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this. After a bit of trial/error, i ended up using a slightly modified version of your solution. I think the issue i was having was because I wasreferring to my userform data (which i had modified the format of earlier in my initiate sub), so i simply amended your code so that my ```strCriteria``` was referring back to the ```ActiveCell.Row``` in my spreadsheet instead and then it worked a treat!! It also meant I didn't have to worry about the date formatting as all values in that column are dates :)

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a random `A` or `B` in columns A and B, and compares them to see if they are the same, and then highlights them if they are.

```
For Each cel In Range("a1:a15")
  cel.Value = Chr(65 + Int(Rnd * 2))
  cel.Offset(0, 1) = Chr(65 + Int(Rnd * 2))
    If cel = cel.Offset(0, 1) Then
      cel.Interior.Color = RGB(220, 210, 210)
      cel.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 210, 210)
    End If
Next cel
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I could understand the task. Please find the following solution. I hope you can modify it according to your final aim. I also included in the next sub an example how to call it. Please let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

```
Sub SelectPolicies(TxtClient As String, dPolicyDate As Date)
    'The following three ranges are covering the part of C and D columns filled with data and the whole A column
    Dim rngClientNames As Range
    Dim rngPolicyDates As Range
    Dim rngOutputID As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policies")
        Set rngClientNames = .Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set rngPolicyDates = .Range("D1:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set rngOutputID = .Range("A:A")
    End With
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rngClientNames.Rows.Count 'Looping throug all the rows

        If rngClientNames(i).Value = TxtClient And rngPolicyDates(i).Value = dPolicyDate Then
            'If the client and the policy date (renewal) is matching write the client into A column
            rngOutputID(i).Value = TxtClient
        Else
            'if not matching, empty the relevant row in A column
            rngOutputID(i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Test()
    'Call the sub with the actual TxtClient and renewal Date.
    'In the test these are in the K1 and L1 cells
    Call SelectPolicies(Range("K1").Value, Range("L1").Value)
End Sub
```